# ColdFusion sort structure by key

Tags: struct, coldfusion

How can I sort a coldfusion structure by key not value.

```
structSort(struct, "text", "asc")
```

It sorts the values, but I would like to sort the key.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: `ListSort(structKeyList(struct))`

Comment: Thanks it returns a list of the struct keys sorted, but I lost the values. I would like to sort the keys but keep the values linked to the keys.

Comment: @user6824563 If you are on CF2016, you can use `structNew("ordered")` and reassign the values to the sorted keys. See my answer for details.

Comment: @user6824563 you can loop over the ordered list and access the structure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are on CF2016, you can use `structNew("ordered")` to create a struct that keeps its insertion order.

```
orderedStruct = structNew("ordered");

structKeys = structKeyArray(struct);
arraySort(structKeys, "text", "asc");

for (key in structKeys) {
    orderedStruct[key] = struct[key];
}

writeDump(orderedStruct);
```

On older versions of CF, you have to rely on Java's LinkedHashMap.

```
orderedStruct = createObject("java", "java.util.LinkedHashMap").init();
```

**But beware** of `orderedStruct` key names now being case sensitive! Also note that dumping a struct will display the entries alphabetically. However, looping over the struct would yield the correct order.

Comment: The shorthand syntax is `orderedStruct = [:];`

Comment: I like the terse syntax